# Grab all tags of a specific type from json block

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a web-app that will return a list of all the editors for a given wikipedia page.  My current set-up is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import json,urllib.request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = text.upper()


    data = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles={text}&rvlimit=500&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment&format=json').read()
    output = json.loads(data)

    return (output)
```

Right now I'm getting the error that 'dictionary is not callable.', but have no such error if I directly print data, instead of output.  My actual question is how to grab all the "User" tags embedded in query >> pages and store that in a list for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract the list of users from the json returned using the following list comprehension. If there is a chance of missing keys in the json returned you will need to update accordingly to handle those scenarios:

```
output = json.loads(data)
users = [revision.get('user') for value in output.get('query').get('pages').values() for revision in value.get('revisions')]
```

Comment: This looks right (and thank you!) but I'm getting the error "name 'value' not defined."  The end of my function now reads: `users = [revision.get('user') for revision in value.get('revisions') for value in output.get('query').get('pages').values()]

 return (','.join(users))` .  Any thoughts?

Comment: That's strange. Can you let me know what value you are using for {text} in the query. I can try test out that endpoint

Comment: I was using "Effective_altruism" as {text}

Comment: I've updated the code now and it should work. Had the for loop on the wrong side (DOH!). The other issue is that the wiki query is case sensitive. When you cast to upper in your code the query returned is empty. Leaving it as it is in your comment returns the users

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[revision.get('user') for revision in list(da.get('query').get('pages').values())[0].get('revisions')]
```

I try it is worker